# Double blue lines in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

How come whenever I type "able to" or "assuming" in word, I get these double blue lines below the word.  They're not squiggly, so I assume they're not grammar errors.  I googled it, but they only had support for single blue squiggly lines, and they were talking about style errors.  I'm fairly certain I don't have a style error, and I just want it to go away because it really distracts me.  Thanks for your help guys

Comment: Hover the word in question and it should pop up with why it underlines it. I think it might suggest a better word due to "talkative writing"

Comment: Yeah... it doesn't do anything when I highlight it.

Comment: How about a screenshot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I found the reason why it's highlighting it.  As @LPChip noted, it's just pointing out that it's kinda wordy.  To fix it, I just right-clicked my word and selected the suggestion in the menu.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get rid of some of the double blue underlines by unchecking "wordiness" in the preferences. I went to Word-->Preferences-->Spelling & Grammar-->Settings button (under Grammar section) and unchecked Wordiness. It's still appearing for some other errors, but at least it's not appearing as much.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is uncheck "check grammar" in Word. Right click on the word with the blue lines underneath, and click grammar. Uncheck "check grammar" but leave "check grammar with spelling" if you want, which is what I did. All blue lines under words will be removed.

Word is programmed to check for things according to the language so it's not always right when you're typing.